# Proper display of layered json data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have json that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Item1",
    "Order": 1,
    "Categories": [
      {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Item1-Subitem1",
        "Order": 1,
        "Subcategories": [
          {
            "Id": 1,
            "Name": "Item1-Subitem1-Subsubitem1",
            "Order": 2
          },
          {
            "Id": 2,
            "Name": "Item1-Subitem1-Subsubitem2",
            "Order": 1
          },
          ...
```

and with angular I need to display on first page (or route) link on main items. For example:
Item1
Item2
And when clicked on them links should be displayed with names from 'Categories'
For example:
Item1-Subitem1
Item1-Subitem2
And when clicked on these links there should be displayed links with name from 'Subcategories'
For example:
Item1-Subitem1-Subsubitem1
Item1-Subitem1-Subsubitem2

Now my first links work but I don't know how to get that nested data from same json according to value from url. When I click on links in first view I go to page I need but without data. No errors is displayed. I belive I need to parse id from url but how to achieve that?
It can be checked here http://plnkr.co/edit/GTfLFQepFcXzXYcIHnP0
I am using ui-router

Comment: Please provide a code snippet to replicate the issue, showing what you've tried already and any error messages or issues you're having. SO is a help forum, not a do-it-for-me forum. Thanks!

Comment: @DACrosby thanks for answer but it would be too much code to write it here. That's why I set plnkr. I don't ask to do it for me just some guidelines because I am stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

In secondList.js, you've defined your scope with the wrong name.  It should be:

```
scope: {
        secondList: '='
    },
```

After you fix that, you're also missing the final factory in service.js:

```
  app.factory('singleList', ['$http', function ($http) {
      return {
          get: function () {
              return $http.get('data.json').then(function (re) {
                  return re.data;
              });
          }
      };
  }])
```

Comment: I added it but I am getting names of List1,List2 for each route now, can it be dynamic? http://plnkr.co/edit/GTfLFQepFcXzXYcIHnP0

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yeah, you've got it accessing the correct templates and using the correct controllers, but your lists are all showing the root level of your json.  I'll take a look...

Comment: My guess off hand is that you should have a single data factory, then pass in a path.  I'll see if I can get it working....

Comment: Thank you for effort, no need to bother more. I will try with your suggestions.

Comment: Gotcha.  If I get a chance, I'll noodle some more - I'm pretty new to the ui-sref design pattern.  I know that you can access the url variables by passing in '$stateParams' to your controllers, which would enable you to walk the json.  

You may also find this handy - I like to use [link](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to mock my json data.  It allows me to spec routes directly to nested json data.  This is probably what you're looking for ultimately, as well.